# Use spritesheet frames as particles?

Tags: sprites, spritesheet, particles, phaser

I want to use frames from a spritesheet as particles for my emitter.

I load my spritesheet with :

```
game.load.spritesheet('particles_sheet', 'http://stuff.lck.io/luckyslot/sprite_sheet.png', 50, 50, 6);

var emitter = game.add.emitter(game.world.centerX, canvas_height, 80);
```

And i need some code to load the right frame at random :

```
emitter.makeParticles('particles_sheet');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to generate a simple array with consecutive values like [0,1,2,3,4,5] starting at 0

```
var particules = 6;
var _pArray = Array.apply(null, {length: particules}).map(Number.call, Number)
```

and then i used this array as a second param in the makeParticles method :

```
emitter.makeParticles('logo_sheet', _pArray );
```

Works perfectly !